# Should the Restart Cinnamon from tty question be reopened or moved to the Unix and Linux StackExchange site?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The [Restart Cinnamon from tty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143838/restart-cinnamon-from-tty) question should not have been locked for the reason "too localized" do to the fact that a large number Ubuntu users who have cinnamon installed may want to know how preform the desired action listed in the question. If you use a good search engine you'll see that that question has been asked many times across various forums and help sites. If this question really is too localized, can it be moved to the Unix and Linux StackExchange site?

Answer (score 4):

As one of the closers - I'm happy to admit this closure was a mistake.

The answer with two upvotes marks the question as being "answered".

Since this is clearly not a bug issue but a valid question for the Cinnamon users community, this should not have been closed.

It has been reopened.

When closing questions - we should be all cognisant of the current answers, the number of votes and thus, whether the question has been accepted as answered by the community even if the OP has not themselves ticked the accepted answer.